# Opera, Firefox has no kiosk option like Chrome gives it openly?

Tags: x11, openbox, kiosk, opera

While using Chrome kiosk mode, i have problem with openbox desktop, its not doing correct for some javascript rendering. So i wanted to test opera and firefox but both does not support kiosk at all like chrome does?

I installed opera and firefox where i am using openbox desktop. When i try to do the following it does not make the full screen mode, and keeps showing the window borders to minimize, maximize (like nonsense).

How do i remove the window borders for firefox/opera to make it full kiosk mode? (like Chrome does!).

```
sun@sun-Alienware-X51:/var/tmp$ export DISPLAY=:0.0 && opera -kioskmode -k -kioskbuttons -kioskresetstation -kioskwindows  -kiosknormalscreen -kioskspeeddial  -nochangebuttons -nochangefullscreen  -nocontextmenu  -nodownload  -noexit  -nohotlist  -nopanel -nokeys  -nomaillinks  -nomenu  -noprint  -nosave  -nosplash  -resetonexit  www.google.com
```

Comment: @terdon: opera -kioskmode is not working in the linux box. i have tried -k --kioskmode etc but it simply not doing any kiosk mode at all.

Comment: Sorry, I read it too quickly, I thought you had to set some settings first but you are quite right, Opera seems to ignore `-kioskmode` I had a quick look around and it seems that kioskmode is broken in opera.

Comment: I tried to recover the issue with Arora, Midori, Firefox. But all has problems, either one does not support full kiosk or something else. Only Chrome was supporting it friendly way but it has problem when it use TWO instance, then the crawling logic does not work.

Comment: The rc.xml that comes with Openbox has an option to start applications with or without decorations:   `<decor>yes</decor>` # enable or disable window decorations. I don't know which OS you're using, but in Lubuntu, the rc.xml file is `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` and the code I mentioned is in the last section, "applications".

Comment: @vasa1: Ubuntu openbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the Firefox Add-On [R-Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) in [my kiosk systems](https://launchpad.net/liab).

Comment: That has problems, i just tried, it shows in my system, a white screen.